# Picasso always download from network

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso

Hi I'm trying to understand how to use the Picasso library to cache my downloaded images, so I created a very simple app with one activity, put an `ImageView` on it and wrote the simplest Picasso line:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://www.estambiente.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Patern_test.jpg")
.placeholder(R.drawable.holder)
.error(R.drawable.error)
.into(im);
```

but I wanted to see the cache indicators, so I wrote this to show them:

```
OkHttpClient picassoClient = new OkHttpClient();
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient)).build();
picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
picasso.load("http://www.estambiente.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Patern_test.jpg").into(im);
```

this code always show the red flag (meaning the image comes from the network) and if I try to open the app while I'm not connected, the error image is shown.

what am I missing here?

Comment: At first it will be loaded from the web and save it to disk cache (blue flag) and if it is used again it will load from memory without closing the app (green flag)

Comment: yes I know this, but the red flag comes in each time I open the app, I've tried each different way posssible (go back, go to home, killng it etc...)

Comment: have you tried this?

http://www.estambiente.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Patern_test.jpg

Comment: yes, the image is correctly showed but it's loaded very slowly and most important not cached!

Comment: Can you precise which version of android you are using ? I guess for a pre kitkat version

Comment: no, it's lollipop (5.1.1)

Comment: Disk caching is done by the HTTP client.  Make sure you have a cache set for yours.  Also, if your client respects cache headers from network responses (as does OkHttp), make sure your server is telling you it is okay to cache (not stale).